# AppCache - manifest error (4)

Tags: google-chrome, html5-appcache

I have hard time to debug why the appcache doesn't work for me. On latest chrome I have got the following errors:

```
 Creating Application Cache with manifest http://localhost/BEST/Home/Manifest
(index):1 Application Cache Checking event
(index):1 Application Cache Error event: Manifest fetch failed (4) http://localhost/BEST/Home/Manifest
```

More specific (from onerror method):

```
     ApplicationCacheErrorEvent {
    message: "Manifest fetch failed (4) http://localhost/BEST/Home/Manifest", 
    status: 4294967295, 
url: "http://localhost/BEST/Home/Manifest", 
reason: "manifest", 
clipboardData: undefined…}
bubbles: false
cancelBubble: false
cancelable: false
clipboardData: undefined
currentTarget: ApplicationCache
defaultPrevented: false
eventPhase: 0
message: "Manifest fetch failed (4) http://localhost/BEST/Home/Manifest"
path: NodeList[0]
reason: "manifest"
returnValue: true
srcElement: ApplicationCache
oncached: null
onchecking: null
ondownloading: null
onerror: function (a,b,c)
onnoupdate: null
onobsolete: null
onprogress: null
onupdateready: null
status: 0
__proto__: ApplicationCache
status: 4294967295
target: ApplicationCache
oncached: null
onchecking: null
ondownloading: null
onerror: function (a,b,c)
onnoupdate: null
onobsolete: null
onprogress: null
onupdateready: nullstatus: 0
__proto__: ApplicationCache
timeStamp: 1425021666357
type: "error"
url: "http://localhost/BEST/Home/Manifest"
__proto__: ApplicationCacheErrorEvent
```

My manifest is very simple:

```
CACHE MANIFEST

CACHE:
Content/DataTables-1.10.3/language/polish.json

NETWORK:
*
```

Even the [manifesto](http://manifesto.ericdelabar.com/) didn't help

[image]

Manifest file is served by ASP.NET MVC action, but doesn't matter I think.
Just in case the code:

```
public ActionResult Manifest()
        {
            //Response.Cache.SetCacheability(System.Web.HttpCacheability.NoCache);
            var text = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(HttpContext.Server.MapPath("../a.appcache"));

            return new ContentResult()
                 {
                     ContentType = "text/cache-manifest",
                     Content = text,
                     ContentEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8
                 };
        }
```

[edit]

On Safari on Win I got

```
Application Cache manifest could not be fetched, because a redirection was attempted.
```

Maybe here is a problem?
This is what I got from fiddler attached to chrome:
[image]

I see, there is a 302, but could it be the problem?
And I doesn't know how to change it to 200.

[edit2]

I set manually the status code in the Manifest action and it started to work:

```
public ActionResult Manifest()
        {
            //Response.Cache.SetCacheability(System.Web.HttpCacheability.NoCache);
            var text = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(HttpContext.Server.MapPath("../BEST.appcache"));

            Response.StatusCode = 200;

            return new ContentResult()
                 {
                     ContentType = "text/cache-manifest",
                     Content = text,  
                     ContentEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8
                 };
        }
```

But only temporary... After few tests, now I got different error. The reason this time is set to signature, not manifest:

```
  Application Cache Error event: Failed to parse manifest http://localhost/BEST/Home/Manifest
(index):252 
ApplicationCacheErrorEvent {
message: "Failed to parse manifest http://localhost/BEST/Home/Manifest", 
status: 0, 
url: "", 
reason: "signature", 
clipboardData: undefined…}
bubbles: false
cancelBubble: false
cancelable: false
clipboardData: undefined
currentTarget: ApplicationCache
defaultPrevented: false
eventPhase: 0
message: "Failed to parse manifest http://localhost/BEST/Home/Manifest"
path: NodeList[0]
reason: "signature"
returnValue: true
srcElement: ApplicationCache
status: 0
target: ApplicationCache
timeStamp: 1425025030583
type: "error"
url: ""
__proto__: ApplicationCacheErrorEvent
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to set the status code to 200 and the no-store header couldn't be defined.